# Perl: Not a GLOB reference

Tags: perl

I get this error for the line: `while($line =<$fh>)`
What does it mean and how can I resolve it?

The entire code is:

```
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use v5.14;  
use Compress::Zlib;  

my $filename= "example.gz";  
my $fh= gzopen($filename, "rb");  

my $line=0;  
my $counter=1;  
my @array=();   

while($line = <$fh>) { # <-- this line
    @array= split (' ', $line);  
    my $num = scalar(@array);  
    print "$array[15]   $array[1]\n" if ($array[15] eq "word");  
    $counter++;  
}  

close $fh;
```

Comment: `gzopen` returns an object, not file handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `$gz->gzreadline($line)` for reading a line of the zip file.

```
while ($gz->gzreadline($line) > 0) {
   @array= split (' ', $line);  
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mpapec has pointed out, `Compress::Zlib::gzopen` doesn't return a file handle.

You could use [PerlIO::gzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::gzip) to get a more perlish api for reading `.gz` files:

```
use PerlIO::gzip;
open my $fh, "<:gzip", "example.gz" or die $!;


while(<$fh>){
   chomp;
   …
}
```

And the line number is generally stored in `$.` so you don't have to count yourself.